# Nonlinear diophantine equations $x^2+2y=z^2$ and $y^2+2x=w^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am asked to find two sets of positive numbers $x$ and $y$, such that both $x^2+2y$ and $y^2+2x$ are perfect squares.

I found a general solution to either single equation, but it seems impossible to satisfy them both. Can it be done, and why or why not?

---

UPDATE: What if $x$ and $y$ are positive rational numbers?

Comment: Is the "update" meant to have $x,y>0$ also, besides allowing rationals?

Comment: Yes, let me fix that.

Comment: I am changing my selected answer from @OC-Sansoo's to individ's because the positive numbers do include the rationals, that is what I was missing. Excellent proof for the natural numbers by OC-Sansoo.

Comment: To be picky, if it is "positive numbers" as in the first version, that might be interpreted to include real number solutions. [Of course the "update" added later excludes irrationals, and Santos interpreted the variables to be integers.]

Comment: @coffeemath True, but Diophantus didn't look for real-valued solutions, only integer- and rational-valued. I was under the mistaken impression that only integers could be used.

Comment: I agree, QuietThud, that Diophantus was only considering rationals in his equations, so specifying that is unnecessary once the equation is called "diophantine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite famous and old task. She is still in the book of Diophantus described.

On this forum I solution stirred, but the topic was deleted.

This system of equations solved before Diophantus.  $$\left\{\begin{aligned}&x^2+ty=z^2\\&y^2+tx=q^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

Although elementary obtained such solutions:  $$x=b-a$$  $$y=b+a$$  $$t=8b$$  $$z=3b+a$$  $$q=3b-a$$

more:  $$x=a-3b$$  $$y=a+b$$  $$t=8(a-b)$$  $$z=3a-b$$  $$q=3a-5b$$

more:  $$x=p^2-10ps-11s^2$$  $$y=2p^2+4ps+38s^2$$  $$t=12(2p+5s)s$$  $$z=p^2+14ps+49s^2$$  $$q=2p^2+10ps-28s^2$$

more:  $$x=p^2+10ps+21s^2$$  $$y=2p^2+12ps+22s^2$$  $$t=-4(2p+5s)s$$  $$z=p^2+2ps+s^2$$  $$q=2p^2+10ps+8s^2$$

But these solutions are not of interest. The fact that a decision that leads Diophantus described sleduyushy formula.  $$x=2psb^2-a^2p^2$$  $$y=2abp^2-b^2s^2$$  $$t=as(4bp-as)$$  $$z=2psb^2+a^2p^2-abs^2$$  $$q=2abp^2+b^2s^2-psa^2$$

I do not think that Diophantus accidentally brought this decision. But then he had to know this formula. Although the cause could not be more simple. And specifically chose not even solution.

If there is some factor before $t - $ the formula enough to divide by this number. This entry solution is better because it allows you to have a more General formula.

Comment: Is the last one known to give all the solutions? Or is it on the other hand meant as a large collection of solutions?

Comment: @coffeemath each formula is its individual approach in solving this system.  I tried to find a formula, and describe whether they are all decisions I'm not interested.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2 + 2y = z^2 \to x^2 < z^2 \to x < z \to x+1 \leq z \to (x+1)^2 \leq z^2$

$y^2 + 2x = w^2 \to y^2 < w^2 \to y < w \to y+1 \leq w \to (y+1)^2 \leq w^2$.

Thus: $(x+1)^2 + (y+1)^2 \leq z^2+w^2$ (*)

But:  $x^2+2y+y^2+2x = z^2 + w^2 \to (x+1)^2+(y+1)^2 = z^2+w^2+2 > z^2 + w^2$ (**).

(*) and (**) contradict each other. So there is no natural solutions.