# $a^2+5b$ and $b^2+5a$ are perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+5b$ and $b^2+5a$ are perfect squares?

When $(a,b)=(4,4)$, both numberes are $4^2+5\cdot 4=36$, which is a perfect square.

Suppose $a\leq b$. Then $b^2+5a\leq b^2+5b$, so $b^2+5a$ must lie strictly between $b^2$ and $(b+3)^2$, which means that it must equal $(b+1)^2$ or $(b+2)^2$. In the first case, $a=(2b+1)/5$, while in the second case, $a=(4b+4)/5$.

Comment: This gives conditions for $b^2+5a$ being square, but nothing  on $a^2+5b$ is square. E.g. $a=8$, $b=9$ gives $b^2+5a=121$ (square), but $a^2+5b=64+45=109$ (not square)

Comment: Note that for example $a=(2b+1)/5$ is quite possible for an integer $b$. It just means 5 is a divisor of $2b+1$ which occurs for example if $b=2,7,...$ etc.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011453/nonlinear-diophantine-equations-x22y-z2-and-y22x-w2 which does your example with 2 instead of 5, but the accepted answer gives some general formulas which may include your case.